# Rendering Reactjs multiple "d3js" child components in the same div

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to use reactjs components for each of my d3js elements. The parent component draws a graph and the child component should draw a donut around it. But right now the render function draw them separately. The following code shows how its appending the graph svg in the parent component (inside `componentDidMount()`):

```
this.svg = select(this.container).append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .classed('network', true)
  .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);
```

Here is the code for the parent component render function:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container" ref={(container) => { this.container = container; }} />
        <div className="donut" >
          <DonutComponent  />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I think one issue is here in the child component, I tried `select("#container")` but it doesn't find it. So I had to use `select("body")` which is appending the donut to a separate div:

```
  var svgContainer = select("body")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("border", "1px solid");
```

How should I change it in the child component? Do I need to change parent render function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to select an id but your container is a class.

```
select(".container") // this should works
```

Comment: Ah that was a silly mistake! Thanks! Now the two SVGs are in the same div. But it still draws them separately. How should I make the donut around the graph?! I think now it's more like a HTML and CSS issue rather than Reactjs!

Comment: Yes, definitely a css problem now,  kind of difficult to find a solution without the svg, could you create a quick plunker ?